# yocto recipe do_install file name with spaces

Tags: yocto

I am trying to install a file name with spaces in rootfs and having problems to overcome it.
I tried escape characters before the space, single quote start + end of the file name without success.

See below the bbappend recipe. I am trying to set default address with NetworkManager.

```
SRC_URI += " \
    file://Wired connection 1.nmconnection \
    file://Wired connection 2.nmconnection \
"

FILES:${PN} += " \
    ${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1.nmconnection  \
    ${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 2.nmconnection \
"

do_install:append() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/Wired connection 1.nmconnection ${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/Wired connection 2.nmconnection ${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/2.2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html) specifies:

> The OpenEmbedded build system does not support file or directory names that contain spaces. Be sure that the Source Directory you use does not contain these types of names.

In the FAQ, they add [this](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/2.2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#idm45929035006304).

But with some additional work, you can use a trick by replacing the spaces by a special character (e.g '_'). For example, rename "Wired connection 1.nmconnection" into "Wired_connection_1.nmconnection". Then, you write a shell function (e.g. named *my_install()*) which restores the original names at installation time with the `tr` command. Call this function from the install task in your recipe:

```
SRC_URI += " \
    file://Wired_connection_1.nmconnection \
    file://Wired_connection_2.nmconnection \
"

my_install () {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections
    file=Wired_connection_1.nmconnection
    install -m 0644 "${WORKDIR}/$file" ${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections
    mv "${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections/$file" "${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections/`echo $file | tr _ ' '`
    file=Wired_connection_2.nmconnection
    install -m 0644 "${WORKDIR}/$file" ${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections
    mv "${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections/$file" "${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections/`echo $file | tr _ ' '`
}

do_install:append() {
    my_install
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rachid,
your answers helped me.
This is my final version:

```
do_install:append() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections 
    file=Wired-connection-1.nmconnection
    install -m 0644 "${WORKDIR}/$file" ${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections
    mv "${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections/$file" "${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections/$(echo $file | tr - \  )"
    file=Wired-connection-2.nmconnection
    install -m 0644 "${WORKDIR}/$file" ${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections
    mv "${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections/$file" "${D}${sysconfdir}/NetworkManager/system-connections/$(echo $file | tr - \  )"
}
```

Comment: You should accept Rachid answer if it has helped you instead of providing one and mark yours as the correct answer... be fair to people who helped you